# jQuery Mobile Load spinner not show?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to test the load spinner with setting a delay? I know in some cases the page is just loading to fast to show the loading spinner. I need to double check to make sure it's loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true)
```

Comment: didn't work I applied it to $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){ ... and all my $.mobile.. stopped loading

Comment: If you just want to test what the loading spinner looks like, load up your page and type the above into your javascript console (firebug,developer tools).